# UIMA Ruta - match previous token

Tags: ruta

Given the example in the RUTA Guide:

`DECLARE Sentence;
PERIOD #{-> MARK(Sentence)} PERIOD;`

I would like to include the first PERIOD in the sentence annotation, is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the first period "." in the sentence annotation? You can do that with the following script.

```
DECLARE Sentence;
(PERIOD #){-> MARK(Sentence)} PERIOD;
```

or

```
DECLARE Sentence;
(PERIOD #){-> Sentence} PERIOD;
```

Using input: "*my first sentence. And my second sentence.*"

You will get ". *And my second sentence*" marked as sentence.

Is that what you try to achieve? I don't think so ;-) I think you want real sentences with the dot at the end of the sentence?

You can do that for example with:

```
DECLARE Sentence;
((# PERIOD){-> Sentence })*;
```

You will get:
"*my first sentence.*"
and " *And my second sentence.*" marked as sentence.

Comment: I have a different use case with the same principle. Thanks !

Comment: Be careful with the last rule since the quantifier for a composed rule element still uses recursion which leads to a StackOverflow. There is a parameter to avoid that, but it's not fully functional.